# Ubuntu on surface laptop 2 keyboard issues

Tags: keyboard, microsoft

Are there any ways of getting the keyboard to work with ubuntu v20.04 on a surface laptop 2? The touch pad works just not the keyboard? Really want to get off windows 10 :(

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with the keyboard?

Comment: See this page: https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface. It seems it's a known issue.